# Which AT commands are understood by a Telebit QBlazer modem?

Tags: modem

Inspired by another post here, I recently purchased a Telebit QBlazer modem and am having some fun with it.

It did not, however, come with a user manual, nor can I find one online.

In the absence of a manual, can someone provide me with specific AT commands that would, e.g. control connection rate or handle any options for this modem that tend to be proprietary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On page seven of the Quick Start Guide, there is the following table:

> The following table lists some common commands. All commands begin with AT and end with pressing the Enter (⏎) key.
>
> ##### Table 1. Common commands
>
> | To... | Type... |
> | --- | --- |
> | Escape to Command Mode | (pause 1 second) +++ (pause 1 second) |
> | Dial a number | AT DT `phone number`⏎ |
> | Hang up | AT H⏎ |
> | Enable V.42bis | AT S180=2⏎ |
> | Enable MNP 5 | AT S180=3⏎ |
> | Enable hardware flow control | AT S58=2 S68=255⏎ |
> | Enable software flow control | AT S58=3 S68=255⏎ |
> | Enable auto-answer | ATS0=1⏎ |
> | Store profile A | AT S255=0 `commands` & W⏎ |
> | Recall profile A | AT S255=0 Z0⏎ |
> | Store profile B | AT S255=1 `commands` & W⏎ |
> | Recall profile B | AT S255=1 Z1⏎ |
> | View active profile | AT & V⏎ |

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the quick-start guide.

Answer (score 5):

Telebit modems were rather consistent in their command abilities. So using the [1994 TrailBlazer 3000/WorldBlazer manual](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_telebit902WorldBlazerModemReference_7147357/) might prove helpful. Of course, everything above V.32 (or V.32bis for the QBlazer+) needs to be ignored.

As always, Bitsaver is your friend for old manuals (and darn long time stable :)) Listing the options as requested would be way outside the scope of an acceptable answer, as there are literally hundreds of options.

Comment: To avoid this being a link-only answer, would you summarize just the relevant AT commands that are proprietary to Telebit modems into the answer?

Comment: @mnem THis is a 189 pag manual. All about the AT command options. Feel encuraged to improve the answer by assigning some imagined relevance.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't personally know enough about the Telebit modems to know what is specifically proprietary to them.  Someone else who knows the differences will have to pull them out of the text, or from other sources, to provide a better answer.